# After repositioning a UITableViewCellEditControl i cant detect the taps on it

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to get a tableView to show some phone numbers like in the contact app.
The thing is, that little red minus-sign on the right of the table view (the UITableViewCellEditControl) that triggers the delete control wont respond to taps after i moved it out of the cell. (I did so by using willTrasistionToState and didTRansitionToState)
In short: I can have my CellEditControl inside of my tableViewCells. It looks like crap, but it works.
I can also shit the control to the left, outside of the cell. That way it looks great, but the control is utterly useless.

I want to have my cake, and eat it too!
I.E. i want the control to be displayed outside of the cell, but fully functional.
Any ideas on how to do this?

I have fiddled with overloading the
`-hitTest: withEvent:` and `-pointInside: withEvent:` methods, but i cant get it to work.

Here is the source of my most succesfull attempt, which wasnt very succesfull at all.

I am doing this in my UITableView-Subclass that i created solely for this purpose.

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews){
        NSLog(@"testing subview: %@", NSStringFromClass(subView.class));
        for (UIView *subsubView in subView.subviews) {
            NSLog(@"testing subsubView: %@", NSStringFromClass(subsubView.class));
            if ([NSStringFromClass(subsubView.class)isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]) {
                CGPoint subsubViewPoint = [subView convertPoint:point fromView:self];
                if ([subsubView hitTest:subsubViewPoint withEvent:event]) {
                    NSLog(@"found it: %@", NSStringFromClass(subsubView.class));
                    return subsubView;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    UIView *returnView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"returnView: %@", NSStringFromClass(returnView.class));
    return returnView;
}
```

But at least it will find the darn view.

EDIT: Here is the Log-Output the above method creates. I know its a lot of text, but it repeats pretty fast.

```
2013-01-29 13:03:21.285 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] -[MKEditableTableView hitTest:withEvent:]
2013-01-29 13:03:21.287 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:21.287 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.288 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.289 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.290 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.291 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.291 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.292 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:21.293 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.294 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.294 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.295 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.296 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.296 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.297 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:21.297 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.298 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.299 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.299 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.300 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.300 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.301 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] found it: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.302 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] -[MKEditableTableView hitTest:withEvent:]
2013-01-29 13:03:21.302 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:21.303 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.303 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.304 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.304 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.305 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.306 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.306 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:21.307 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.321 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.323 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.324 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.325 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.325 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.326 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:21.326 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.327 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.327 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.328 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.328 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.329 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.329 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] found it: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.330 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] -[MKEditableTableView hitTest:withEvent:]
2013-01-29 13:03:21.341 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:21.342 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.343 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.343 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.344 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.344 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.345 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.345 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:21.346 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.346 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.347 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.347 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.348 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.362 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.363 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:21.363 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.364 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.365 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:21.365 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.366 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:21.366 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:21.367 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] found it: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.061 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] -[MKEditableTableView hitTest:withEvent:]
2013-01-29 13:03:22.062 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:22.063 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.064 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.065 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.066 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.066 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.067 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.068 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:22.069 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.069 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.070 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.070 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.071 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.072 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.072 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:22.073 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.074 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.074 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.075 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.076 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.076 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.077 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] found it: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.077 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] -[MKEditableTableView hitTest:withEvent:]
2013-01-29 13:03:22.078 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:22.079 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.079 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.080 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.080 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.081 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.081 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.082 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:22.083 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.083 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.084 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.084 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.085 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.085 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.086 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:22.087 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.087 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.088 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.088 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.089 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.089 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.090 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] found it: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.091 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] -[MKEditableTableView hitTest:withEvent:]
2013-01-29 13:03:22.091 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:22.092 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.093 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.107 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.109 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.110 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.111 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.111 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:22.112 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.112 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.113 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.113 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.114 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.114 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.115 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subview: MKEditableTableViewCell
2013-01-29 13:03:22.115 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellContentView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.128 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.129 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITextField
2013-01-29 13:03:22.129 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.130 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UIView
2013-01-29 13:03:22.131 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] testing subsubView: UITableViewCellEditControl
2013-01-29 13:03:22.131 MaklerKid[2559:fb03] found it: UITableViewCellEditControl
```

NEXT EDIT:
Since there seems to be some confusion as to what im trying to do (dont mind the "why" right now) here are some pictures to clarify:

Picture one: This works, but looks sucky:

[image: This is not what i want!]

Picture two: This looks good, but doesnt work:

[image: I want this!]

Also i found out that the control will still receive the touches if i click on the spot where it used to be. That is: If, in scenario 2, i tap on the spot where the controls are in scenario 1 (i.e. inside the cell), the code will be executed and the DeleteControl will appear. Does this make sense to anybody? Not me, thats for sure.

ANOTHER EDIT:

Some people offered suggestions like "rebuild the Cell, so there is enough space for the control in it", but i cannot do that. Period.
Also, it has been suggested that i should not "break apples design patterns".
I have attached a snapshot of my contacts app in editing mode. Please do note that the EditingControl is OUTSIDE of the Cell, like in this picture (i removed the name and numbers for privacy):

Picture 3:

[image]

Please help me, i am completely lost on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a tapGestureRecognizer anywhere?

Comment: Nope. I tried, but it didnt get me anywhere, so i removed it.

Comment: Why do you want the delete control outside of the cell? What is that supposed to look like? The Contacts app doesn't do this, it just uses a standard grouped table view...

Comment: Im sorry, i should have been celarer in my description: I want the look that the contacts app gets when you hit "EDIT" on one of your contacts. The TableView will become editable, and the little red minus sign will appear outside of the cells. Mind you, i am not trying to move the actual UITableViewCellDeleteControl (the button that says "delete"), but the UITableViewCellEditControl, aka the little red circle with a minus-sign in it. As to why do i want this, i dont. Some designer said to make it so, and im not arguing.

Comment: why dont you build the cells so the editControl appears on the right place and you dont have to move it? Much simpler and you dont have to mess up the internal view-layout of apple.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind suggestions, but i cannot change anything in the layout. These cells have a specified size that fits other elements in the view. If I change their size, the layout will be broken. If i change the internal cell design, there wont be enough space for the data to be displayed. Im sorry, but its just not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried turning it off and on again?

but for real, i think you are looking for the "AddressBook.framework" (Address Book UI Framework) here.

[Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1) to the Guide, hope you will find what you seek!

Comment: Actually, this turned out to be quite helpful. Theres an ABPersonViewController that mimicks the look and feel of the Contacts-App completely. Ill have to find a way to change the background and some color, but that will be manageable, i guess. thx dude...